# Calculating required headheight for fancyhdr, unexpectedly not linear

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to calculate the height for a header created with `fancyhdr`. The actual format is a bit more complicated and depends on the return value of some commands (hard coding is not possible). I tried to calculate the needed height based on the the fontsize and known spacing. However this doesn't match what `fancyhdr` expects.

If I purposely set a headerheight that is too small, fancyhdr suggests a size for the header. This value works every time, but doesn't scale linear with the number of lines. A MWE is written below.

I have three questions:

1. Why are these values as they are?
2. How do I calculate the height properly?
3. Is it possible to get fancyhdr's estimation (pre-render) by LaTeX code?

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.0in, tmargin=1.0in, bmargin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{customone}{
\fancyhf{}

    \lhead{
        Line 1
    }
}

\fancypagestyle{customtwo}{
    \fancyhf{}

    \lhead{
        Line 1\\
        Line 2
    }
}

\fancypagestyle{customthree}{
    \fancyhf{}

    \lhead{
        Line 1\\
        Line 2\\
        Line 3
    }
}

\pagestyle{customtwo}

\begin{document}
\noindent The minimum required \textit{headheight} for \textit{customone} is 14.49998pt.\\
The minimum required \textit{headheight} for \textit{customtwo} is 27.04604pt.\\
The minimum required \textit{headheight} for \textit{customthree} is 41.5604pt.\\
The height difference between \textit{customone} and \textit{customtwo} is 12.54606pt.\\
The height difference between \textit{customtwo} and \textit{customthree} is 14.51436pt.\\
The heights divided by the number of lines are: 14.49998pt, 13.52302pt, 13.853466pt.
\end{document}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header/footer content is set inside a box, and this box doesn't really form part of the regular text box/content. As such, it doesn't set itself with the same baseline skip (line height and depth). So, in order for you to see a consistent head height used by the header, set the content inside a `tabular`, or use `\strut`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1.5in, rmargin=1.0in, tmargin=1.0in, bmargin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{customone}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \lhead{%
    \strut Line 1%
  }%
}

\fancypagestyle{customtwo}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \lhead{%
    \begin{tabular}{ c }
      Line 1\\
      Line 2
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\fancypagestyle{customthree}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \lhead{%
    \begin{tabular}{ c }
        pine 1\\
        Line 2\\
        Line 3
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\pagestyle{customone}
%\pagestyle{customtwo}
%\pagestyle{customthree}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

The minimum required \texttt{\string\headheight} for \texttt{customone} is 14.49998pt. \par
The minimum required \texttt{\string\headheight} for \texttt{customtwo} is 28.99997pt. \par
The minimum required \texttt{\string\headheight} for \texttt{customthree} is 43.49995pt. \par
The height difference between \texttt{customone} and \texttt{customtwo} is 14.49999pt. \par
The height difference between \texttt{customtwo} and \texttt{customthree} is 14.49998pt. \par
The heights divided by the number of lines are: 14.49998pt, 14.499985pt, 14.49998333pt.

%\texttt{\string\baselineskip}: \the\baselineskip% 14.5pt under 12pt base font size

\end{document}
```

So, if you set the content with a consistent baselines skip, you can use multiples of `\baselineskip` and be safe knowing things will fit; the `\baselineskip` for a `12pt` base font size is `14.5pt`. The deviations of `\headheight` are due to rounding.